# My touchscreen does not work, need a way to remote control phone

Tags: touchscreen, remote-control

My touch screen on my LG GT540 gone totally unresponsive. I would like to do some final things on the phone, before recycling it. It is a rooted, runs 2.3 cyanogenmod, has usb debug switched on. Is there an app, which can control it via USB?

Please note, that all solutions, that needs even a touch on the screen won't work. And I guess I have to unlock the phone (not a security lock).

thanks

Comment: I stumbled on an app which when installed in your computer running Windows can access the phone (connected through USB) as if you can remotely access it. It does not require any app installation, but require a rooted phone with USB debugging on. On the PC side, it needs Android SDK installed. I first came to know about it through one of a comment in this forum. But very unfortunately I could not remember the app name. Posting as a comment so that if any one can remember can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for [paid app]: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vmlite.vncserver&hl=en

However, if you are willing to go through a lengthy process [but free], you can follow the tutorial [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/42491/how-to-remote-view-and-control-your-android-phone/) to access your phone via PC.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have the time to try it. The process is not lengthy, you just have to start a java app from the web, if you have android SDK. And it works!!!

Answer (score 4):

Give [androidscreencast](http://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/) a try.  You may already need to have USB Debugging enabled for it to work, but you've said you already have that enabled, so should be ok.  It just needs a USB connection to the phone and goes over the ADB protocol.

Comment: yep, that's what @input suggested

Answer (score 1):

Use a USB-OTG cable to connect a mouse. You can even make your own by cutting and soldering a microUSB cable to the female end of a USB extension cable.

Answer (score 0):

Scrcpy is awesome!
It uses adb directly for backend and it doesn't block those remote screen restricted apps too. And since it's adb. You can remote control via same network wirelessly.

For linux users. It's available on most of package managers.